# kubectl apply of converted deployment didn't appear to do anything

Tags: kubernetes

We have ten or so k8s clusters all running v1.13.  We're going to be upgrading all of them in a couple of months to v1.24.

We use helm for templating, but we use kubectl for actual deployments.

A different team is going to convert the existing clusters (one at a time, with testing), but only the nodes and system processes.  They're going to leave the live objects running.  My team is responsible for the helm charts that are used in builds, so we're going to make the required `apiVersion` changes there.

I believe we will have to patch the live objects, upgrading `apiVersion` values where necessary.  I already examined the "deprecation guide" and also checked "kubent", so I see that some objects are using a version that is deprecated AND removed, in the target version.  If it were only deprecated, the existing object with the old `apiVersion` would work.

I then tried to perform an experiment of converting a single deployment.  I did a `kubectl get` of the deployment to a file, then I ran a `kubectl convert -f file` and stored that output in a file (I know that I technically should specify the output version, but in this case it's the same as the latest version).

I inspected that file and verified that it had the correct newer version.

I then ran `kubectl apply -f convertedfile`.  It appeared to complete successfully.

I then ran `kubectl get deployment ...` and looked at the output.  It was still using the old version ("extensions/v1beta1").  I don't understand why.

I tried repeating this process with varying values of "-v=" on the "apply" call.  I first tried it with 99 and that resulted in seemingly infinite output.  It appeared to be printing text in hex/char form, but many thousands and thousands of lines, seemingly repeating.  I aborted that and started over at 1 and went forward slowly.

At "-v=5", I got the following:

```
I1207 15:15:53.484805   37200 request.go:1145]
body was not decodable (unable to check for Status): couldn't get version/kind;
json parse error:
  json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type struct 
    { APIVersion string "json: \"apiVersion,omitempty\""; 
      Kind string "json:\"kind,omitempty\"" 
    }
```

But it still said `deployment.apps/... configured` after that.

I looked at the "converted" file, and I didn't see anything wrong with it.  It begins with this:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
```

**Update**:

I even tried changing this process, adding a step to delete the existing deployment before applying the converted one, which I felt pretty certain would work.  Strangely, this made no difference. After the "`apply`" of the file using the new version, I re-got the object again, and it was back to the old version again (just in case you think of this, I did verify that after the `delete`, the object actually was deleted).  I am befuddled.

**Update**:

I'll self-answer a while later, but for now I'll provide some basic info.

Apparently there's a notion of "api groups" that I was vaguely aware of, but I didn't know some of the complexities of it.

When I say something like "`kubectl get deployment ...`", the term "`deployment`" isn't really an api group, it's something that is used to find an api group to use, and the first one it finds is the "`extensions/...`" api group.  Which api group is used actually controls what `apiVersion` is returned in objects queried through `kubectl`.  If you end up using the "`extensions/...`" api group, you'll get the "`extensions/...`" version.  If you instead do something like "`kubectl get deployments.v1.apps ...`", the term "`deployments.v1.apps`" IS an api group, and the version corresponding to that api group is "`apps/v1`", so the `apiVersion` returned in that object is "`apps/v1`".

It's now not clear to me exactly what k8s 1.24 will do if the stored k8s object has `apiVersion` "`extensions/...`", even if it is requested using "`deployments.v1.apps`".  We do have some clusters already running that version, so I'll run some experiments to see what actually happens.